# Vue jest $refs function and component mocking issue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm using a node module called headroom for one of my vue components. I'm trying to mock the library and write the test but i'm getting a `this.$refs.headroom._setHeightOffset is not a function` it seems like the function in the $ref isn't defined.

**Vue Component**

```
<script>
  import { headroom } from 'vue-headroom';

  name: 'Test',

  components: {
    headroom    
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$refs.headroom._setHeightOffset();
  }
</script>

<template>
 <headroom ref="headroom">
   <OtherComponent />
  <headroom>
</template>
```

In my test file I'm doing a shallowMount and mocking the imported library like below but it still isn't picking up the function in my test.

```
jest.mock('vue-headroom', () => ({
  name: 'headroom',
  headroom: {
    _setHeightOffset: jest.fn(),
  },
}));
```

I tried mocking it like this as well but still didn't work.
`wrapper.vm.$refs.headroom._setHeightOffset =  jest.fn();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use mount if you want to try to mock internal method `_setHeightOffset`.

Or you can use shallow mount and then create stub on headroom.

**Why?** Because `headroom` there is child component of your custom Test Vue Component. which headroom has been stub automatically if you use shallowMount. Reference: [shallowMount](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount).

I created several example on how to spy or mock it. You can choose which one suitable for you.

```js
// File: ComponentTest.spec.js
import { headroom } from 'vue-headroom';
import { mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Component from '@/components/ComponentTest.vue';

describe('ComponentTest.vue', () => {
  it('example spy & mount', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(headroom.methods, '_setHeightOffset');
    const wrapper = mount(Component);
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });

  it('example mock & mount', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    headroom.methods._setHeightOffset = mock;
    const wrapper = mount(Component);
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });

  it('example mock & shallow mount', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    headroom.methods._setHeightOffset = mock;
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
      stubs: {
        headroom,
      },
    });
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

Example Test Component (simplified)

```js
// File ComponentTest.vue
<script>
import { headroom } from 'vue-headroom';

export default {
  name: 'Test',
  components: { headroom },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.headroom._setHeightOffset();
  },
};
</script>
<template>
 <headroom ref="headroom">
   xxx
  </headroom>
</template>
```

Then I run jest to run ComponentTest.spec.js

```
$ npx jest ComponentTest.spec.js 
 PASS  test/ComponentTest.spec.js
  ComponentTest.vue
    ✓ example spy & mount (12 ms)
    ✓ example mock & mount (2 ms)
    ✓ example mock & shallow mount (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.176 s
```

**Note:**
I use `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)`. Why? because the internal method has been called inside [headroom.vue](https://github.com/dalphyx/vue-headroom/blob/e9257e8a9e54a33c7bd22ce87e5db7d8f5675a13/src/headroom.vue#L112), and you try to call it again.

Comment: Is this pulling in the actually component in the stub? Is it possible to mock that bit and just test the component itself?

Comment: This did get me very much there i just mocked headroom like so const headroom = {
  template: '<div />',
  methods: {
    _setHeightOffset() {},
  },
};

thanks for your help

Comment: All 3 "it" have purpose to test your target component (name: Test). The one which get stub/mock is child of target component (in this context is: headroom).